# Почему не работает свойство border-color?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, border

В CSS для ссылки написан данный код. Все свойства работают корректно, при компиляции ошибок не найдено, но цвет границы не отображается

```
.main_nav_item{
display:block;
background-color: cornflowerblue;
border: 20px;
border-color: darkgreen;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: 240px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

Вот код из HTML:

```
<head>
   <header>
        <h1 id='title'>*****</h1>
        <ul id='main_navigation'>
            <li><a href="#" class='main_nav_item'>Директора</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class='main_nav_item'>Учительский состав</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class='main_nav_item'>Медалисты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class='main_nav_item'>Выдающиеся выпускники</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</head>
```

В чём проблема?
Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый. Искала похожие вопросы, но ответа не нашла.

Comment: можно просто написать border: 20px solid darkgreen;  в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

надо еще `border-width` указать, или указать просто `border: 20px solid darkgreen`

```css
.main_nav_item{
display:block;
background-color: cornflowerblue;
border: 20px solid darkgreen;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: 240px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

Comment: `border-width`  у ТС указан, пусть и не очень красиво. Отсутствует стиль рамки - `border-style`

Comment: Всё заработало. Спасибо огромное! Ещё раз извините за глупый вопрос